# Azure created DefaultResourceGroup-EAU resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Today I am noticing that the Azure Group, I dont know when Azure created the

> "**DefaultResourceGroup-EAU**" resource group, and in this group two item is placed
>   [image]

I am not using any Azure Container Registry service and AKS, should I remove this group because it paying in my invoice, I just only have Azure Web Apps and Azure SQL databases and one VM only, should its impact on my above mentioned services after deletion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

certainly not in terms of how those services function, but monitoring might be impaired if you delete those.
Those resources look like they were created alongside AKS cluster. Doesn't mean that they were only being used for that, but highly likely.

Comment: You might be rigth that few days back I have created AKS on portal and didn't noticed that this group created, last day I deleted the AKS and this not,

Comment: right, this would not get deleted when you delete the aks resource or aks resource group, because its sitting in a separate resource group

Comment: So point is that should I delete it and it will not effecting  my other services.

Comment: most likely not, you can check diagnostic settings on those and see if they point to this OMS workspace, but even if they do, those sinks would just stop working

Comment: log analytics workspace, whatever they are called now :)